# SELinux Blocks Tomcat 7 Service in RHEL 7 after Yum update

Tags: permissions, redhat, tomcat7

I performed a Yum update and Tomcat's ability to access file has been broken.

```
SEVERE: Failed to load keystore type JKS with path /var/websvr/certs/keyfile.jks due to /var/websvr/certs/keyfile.jks (Permission denied)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/websvr/certs/keyfile.jks (Permission denied)
```

Even though the tomcat user has `ownership and full permissions` of not only the file, but the entire directory

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 tomcat   tomcat 4829 Aug 19  2016 keyfile.jks
```

and I have verified that `Tomcat` is running under `tomcat user`.  So, why is access still being prevented?

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)

**Edit**

From [A.B](https://serverfault.com/users/217515/a-b)'s comment - the `/var/log/audit/audit.log` :

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1511208892.087:392): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=770 comm="java" name="keyfile.jks" dev="xvda2" ino=9641897 scontext=system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
```

So it **appears this is SELinux related**.  I have tried to resolve, but posts like [this one](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3174331) require a Red Hat subscription.

Using [RH Doc for SELinux & Apache](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/chap-managing_confined_services-the_apache_http_server#sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-The_Apache_HTTP_Server_and_SELinux), in conjunction with [RH SELinux Doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-selinux_contexts_labeling_files-persistent_changes_semanage_fcontext) -  I think to resolve this, the `keyfile.jks` file must be labelled with:

```
tomcat_t:tomcat_t:tomcat_sys_content_t:s0
```

which is read-only access for confined user tomcat_t in role tomcat_t.  The file is currently labelled:

```
unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0
```

to get past additional SELinux file restrictions.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: from RHEL7.4, afaik, tomcat got selinux contexts instead of running unconfined. So I'd check `/var/log/audit/audit.log` for lines having the word `denied` and related to your problem.

Comment: Registration is free on https://developer.redhat.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to label /var/websvr/certs/keyfile.jks with tomcat_sys_content_t then you can create a customer file context

```
semanage fcontext -a /var/websvr/certs/keyfile.jks -t tomcat_sys_content_t
restorecon /var/websvr/certs/keyfile.jks
```

If that doesn't work because tomcat_sys_content_t doesn't exist then substitute **tomcat_t** or possibly **pki_tomcat_cert_t** in the command above.

Comment: Using ` pki_tomcat_cert_t `  worked.  Thank you.